# Student Info Program (adding onto) How to add two methods

Tags: python

We are adding onto code that we completed last week. Our instructor gave us direction (posted at bottom) and to me and my partner, they are not very descriptive. I'm not asking for an answer to the code, but just a different and more informative description or hints at how to start these additions.

```py
import math

class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, student_id, intended_major, grade):
        self.name = name
        self.student_id = student_id
        self.intended_major = intended_major
        self.grade = grade
        self._exams = []
        self._quizzes = []
        self._projects = []

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_student_id(self):
        return self.student_id

    def get_major(self):
        return self.intended_major

    def set_quizzes(self, _quizzes):
        self._quizzes = _quizzes[:]

    def set_exams(self, _exams):
        self._exams = _exams[:]

    def set_projects(self, _projects):
        self._projects = _projects[:]

    def get_exams_mean(self):
        return float((sum(self._exams)) / max(len(self._exams), 1))

    def get_exams_median(self):
        if len(self._exams) == 0:
            return 0

        lst = sorted(self._exams)

        if len(lst) % 2 == 0:
            n1 = lst[int(len(lst)/2)]
            n2 = lst[int(len(lst)/2)-1]
            return ( n1 + n2 ) / 2
        else:
            return lst[int(len(lst) / 2)]

    def get_exams_std_dev(self):
        if len(self._exams) == 0:
            return 0

        mean = sum(self._exams) / len(self._exams)
        total = 0
        for i in self._exams:
            total += (i - mean)**2
        return math.sqrt(total/len(self._exams))

    def get_quizzes_mean(self):
        return float((sum(self._quizzes)) / max(len(self._quizzes), 1))

    def get_quizzes_median(self):
        if len(self._quizzes) == 0:
            return 0

        lst = sorted(self._quizzes)

        if len(lst) % 2 == 0:
            n1 = lst[int(len(lst) / 2)]
            n2 = lst[int(len(lst) / 2) -1]
            return ( n1 + n2 ) / 2
        else:
            return lst[int(len(lst) / 2)]

    def get_quizzes_std_dev(self):
        if len(self._quizzes) == 0:
            return 0

        mean = sum(self._quizzes) / len(self._quizzes)
        total = 0
        for i in self._quizzes:
            total += (i - mean) ** 2
        return math.sqrt(total / len(self._quizzes))

    def get_projects_mean(self):
        return float((sum(self._projects)) / max(len(self._projects), 1))

    def get_projects_median(self):
        if len(self._projects) == 0:
            return 0

        lst = sorted(self._projects)

        if len(lst) % 2 == 0:
            n1 = lst[int(len(lst)/2)]
            n2 = lst[int(len(lst)/2)-1]
            return ( n1 + n2 ) / 2
        else:
            return lst[int(len(lst) / 2)]

    def get_projects_std_dev(self):
        if len(self._projects) == 0:
            return 0

        mean = sum(self._projects)/len(self._projects)
        total = 0
        for i in self._projects:
            total += (i - mean)**2
        return math.sqrt(total/len(self._projects))

    def set_grade_calculation_type(self):
        if True:
            return 0
        else:
            pass

    def set_quiz(self, grade, number):
        pass
```

Add stubs for the following instance methods to your Student class:

- set_grade_calculation_type:
  The method takes a Boolean argument: True calculates missing grades as zero; 
  False skips missing grades in calculations
  You will need to store this value in your class
  Default to True if this method is not called
- set_quiz:
  takes two arguments: grade and number, which identifies the quiz
  If the quiz list has less than number elements, then add missing quizzes as 
  None
  Since this is computer science, we will start with quiz 0.
  For example, let's say the student has two quiz grades in list for quizzes 0 
  and 1 =[90, 78], and we call student.set_quiz(89,4). We are missing quizzes 2 
  and 3, so our updated list will be [90, 78, None, None, 89]. In the future if 
  we call student.set_quiz(93,2) we would have [90, 78, 93, None, 89].
- set_exam: analogous to set_quiz
- set_project: analogous to set_quiz

Comment: What does it mean to calculate grades? The class takes a `grade` argument.

Comment: I believe "calculate grades" means when the grades are calculated in the mean, median, and std_dev functions but I'm not 100% sure. I asked my instructor and all he said was "It's already in there"....

Comment: So I'm guessing he wants you to compute the final grade taking into account the grades of the projects, exams and quizzes right?

Comment: i'd like to understand something. The code so far, is it written by you or was this provided to you? More specifically, are you comfortable with the sentence: `Add stubs for the following instance methods to your Student class` . Given a simpler method, say one that prints "hello world", could you then add it in?

Comment: That's what I'm assuming. I just asked him again and he said that for the set_grade_calculation_type method, it should return 0 if there is no grade entered in one of the lists if True, and False would just skip the missing grades. What he said doesn't make sense because in what instance would it return True and what instance would it return False? I don't think those instances can be differentiated.

Comment: The code so far has been written by me and my partner. I am comfortable adding a method that would print "hello world". His instructions and the way he describes things do not make sense to me

Comment: I will have you know that, in Python, getters and setters aren't typical since you can directly access any class variable by doing `student_object.variable`. Either way, your instructor isn't very clear about the `set_grade_calculation_type` function. Before moving any further, you should add a parameter to your class function and do the coding according to it's boolean value.

Comment: I read the `set_grade_calculation_type` instructions as: 1 - create a new instance variable, type boolean,  with a default value of True. Create a setter method that can set it to true or false. Then, update your grade calc methods to use this new variable - which would make a big difference in places you are using length (the skipped vs zero).

Comment: The sentence `The method takes a Boolean argument` is pretty clear as to what the function should look like: `def set_grade_calculation_type(self, bool_value=True)`. Then compute the grade according to the grades of the projects/quizes/exams and update the class parameter : `self.grade = computed_grade`

Comment: The default needs to be in `__init__` - since "Default to True if this method is not called"